# minimizing a pairwise sum with respect to a sequence of integers

Tags: optimization, matrices

Let $m$ and $n$ be two integers, where $m \leq n$.
Suppose you are given $m^2$ matrices $W^{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ for $i, j \in \{1, \dots, m\}$.

The goal is to find a sequence $a$ of $m$ integers $a_i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ minimizing

$$
\min_a \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m W^{i,j}_{a_i, a_j}
$$

Does this problem  have an established name?

The total enumeration takes $n^m$ steps. I'm interested in $m \approx 10$ and $n \approx 100$, if not larger. So I wonder if there are better algorithms that should work here aside from simulated annealing and genetic algorithms?

Comment: This seems to be a long shot, but you could try to reduce SAT to this problem in such a way that SETH-conjecture implies the time lower-bound you specified (assuming negative results). For that given a formula of $N$ variables, you should build an instance such that $m \log n = N$.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm that gives the exact optimum, or heuristics that give a pretty-good solution but may or may not give the optimal solution?

Comment: @D.W. Good heuristics, I guess, assuming that exact algorithms are inefficient ($n^m$ steps)

Comment: Is there any structure to W at all?

Comment: @TickaJules For the purposes of this question, $W$s are arbitrary.

Comment: I was able to write a linear program that at least produces a lower bound on the optimal solution.  It requires $NM+(NM)^2$ variables and similar number of constraints, which on my toy example solves to a non-integer solution (providing the lower bound).

Comment: @TickaJules *integer* linear program? Aren't they NP-hard?

Comment: In general yes.